# cannot pass form data inside module of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a custom module in ruby on rails with name Admin. But I could not save form data(name, email, password) while signup.Please help me...

**User Controller**

```
  module Admin
  class UsersController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :authenticate, :except => [:show, :new, :create]
    before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update]
    before_filter :admin_user,   :only => :destroy


     def index
      @title = "All users"
      # @users = User.all
      @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])
     end

    def new
      @title = "Sign up"
      @user = User.new
    end

    def show
       @user = User.find(params[:id])
       @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(:page => params[:page])
       @title = @user.name
    end

    def create
      @user = User.new(params[:user])
      if @user.save
        sign_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
        redirect_to @user
      else
        @title = "Sign up"
        render 'new'
      end
    end

    def edit
      # @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @title = "Edit user"  
    end

    def update
      # @user = User.find(params[:id])
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
        redirect_to @user
      else
        @title = "Edit user"
        render 'edit'
      end
    end

    def destroy
      User.find(params[:id]).destroy
      flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
      redirect_to users_path
    end

    def following
      @title = "Following"
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @users = @user.following.paginate(:page => params[:page])
      render 'show_follow'
    end

    def followers
      @title = "Followers"
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @users = @user.followers.paginate(:page => params[:page])
      render 'show_follow'
    end


    private
      #10.2
      def current_user?(user)
        user == current_user
      end

      def correct_user
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
      end

      def admin_user
        redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user && current_user.admin?
      end

  end
end
```

**User Model**

```
 module Admin
  require 'digest'

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base

     attr_accessor :password
     attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

     has_many :microposts, :dependent => :destroy
     has_many :relationships, :foreign_key => "follower_id",
                             :dependent => :destroy
     has_many :following, :through => :relationships, :source => :followed
     has_many :reverse_relationships, :foreign_key => "followed_id", 
                                      :class_name => "Relationship",
                                      :dependent => :destroy
     has_many :followers, :through => :reverse_relationships, :source => :follower
     has_many :replies, foreign_key: "to_id", class_name: "Micropost"
     validates :name, :presence => true , :length => { :maximum => 50 } 

     email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
     validates :email, :presence => true, :format => { :with => email_regex },
                      :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
     validates :password, :presence => true,
                         :confirmation => true,
                         :length => {:within => 6..40}

    before_save :encrypt_password


    def feed
      Micropost.from_users_followed_by_including_replies(self)
    end

    def has_password?(submitted_password)
     encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password) 
    end

    def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password) # class method!
     user = find_by_email(email)
     # return nil if user.nil?
     # return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)

     user && user.has_password?(submitted_password) ? user : nil
    end
    def self.authenticate_with_salt(id, cookie_salt)
      user = find_by_id(id)
      (user && user.salt == cookie_salt) ? user : nil
    end

    def following?(followed)
      relationships.find_by_followed_id(followed)
    end

    def follow!(followed)
      relationships.create!(:followed_id => followed.id)
    end

    def unfollow!(followed)
      relationships.find_by_followed_id(followed).destroy
    end

    def shorthand
     # name.gsub(/\s*/,"")
     name.gsub(/ /,"_")
    end
    def self.shorthand_to_name(sh)
     # name.gsub(/\s*/,"")
     sh.gsub(/_/," ")
    end
    def self.find_by_shorthand(shorthand_name)
      all = where(name: User.shorthand_to_name(shorthand_name))
      return nil if all.empty?
      all.first
    end

   private 
      def encrypt_password
        self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
        self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
      end
      def encrypt(string)
        secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
      end  
      def make_salt
        secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
      end
      def secure_hash(string)
        Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
      end    
  end
end
```

**User View**

```
<h1>Sign up</h1>
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'fields', :f => f %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here name and email cannot be save in db even password is saved and new record is  created..

Comment: you should check logs - if you see that request comes to `Admin::UsersController` with correct params then a problem can be with validations. You can check it easily by changing `@user.save` on `@user.save!` and submit your form again. If user is invalid you will see validation error.

Comment: There is still some information missing. Given you are in a module I expect slightly nonstandard routes, so please post the relevant part of your `routes.rb`. Then we should see how your data arrives at your endpoint. Could you print out the params you get or check them in the logs and post them as @gotva suggested?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400750/cannot-save-form-data-inside-module-of-rails

Comment: SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: INSERT INTO "users" ("admin", "created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "name", "salt", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)